# Filter Using Checkboxes w. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, filter

I am trying to create checkbox filters that show or hide boxes on my pagebased on their id. I'm very new to jquery, but have been playing around with this for a while and cannot seem to get the boxes to hide / show. Please see my code below. Thanks!

Sport model

```
class Sport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Snippet of HTML to filter

```
{% for game in game_list %}
                            {% if game.sport = sport %}
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <section id="{{ sport.name }}" class="box pick-game">
                                        <div class="box box-content">
                                            <div class="game-bet-header">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                                         <h4 class="game-date"> {{ game.time|time }} - {{ game.time|date:"M-d" }}</h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <h4 class="game-title">{{ game.team1 }} vs {{ game.team2 }} </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

HTML Checkboxes to Use as Filters

```
<div class="sport-sidebar">
            <section class="sports-box">
                {% for sport in sports %}
                    <div id="sport-filter" class="sport-name">
                        <label for="filter-{{ sport.name }}"><input type="checkbox" class="sport" value="{{ sport.name }}" id="filter-{{ sport.name }}">{{ sport.name }}</label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </section>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#sport-filter input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $('#sport-filter input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        $("#" +$(this).val()).show()
    });
});
```

Please help provide suggestions to solve this problem! Thanks so much

**Updated Javascript on 9/20, but still not working**

Please see below for updated javascript. Initializing with .hide() is not working, but if I manually set the id of each sport to display: none in the CSS it does hide. This is leading me to believe that either .show and .hide are not working, or they are not correctly capturing my class. I also added a class to my checkbox in the javascript to distinguish it from the others.

```
$("#mlb-pick").hide();
$("#nfl-pick").hide();


$(".sport-sidebar input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function() {
  var thisval =  $(this).val();
  if ($(this).prop('checked')){
      $('#' + thisval+"-pick").show();
    }
  else{
    $('#' + thisval).hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: I can't run your code snippet, but seems that your error is on the "each" method. note that you can run `.each(function(index, item){ $(item).show() })`

Comment: any suggestions how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working one with your example, you've had to put the "id" for the sections, or in other case, change the jquery selector for it's class.

Also you have to set the click action for the input checkbox elements.

Hope this helps.

```js
//initialize state
$("#mlb").hide();
$("#nfl").hide();


$("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function() {
  var thisval =  $(this).val();
  if ($(this).prop('checked')){
      $('#' + thisval).show();
    }
  else{
    $('#' + thisval).hide();
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sport-filter" class="mlb">
     <label for="mlb-filter"><input type="checkbox" value="mlb" id="mlb-filter">mlb</label>
</div>
 <div id="sport-filter" class="nfl">
     <label for="nfl-filter"><input type="checkbox" value="nfl" id="nfl-filter">nfl</label>
</div>

<section class=mlb id="mlb">
  <p>
    Hey
  </p>
</section>
<section class=nfl id="nfl">
  <p>
    Hey 2
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your continue help Jordy. Still continuing to get errors with the filtering -- the .hide and .show are not working as described as above, and neither is the filter. Your code in the fiddle is working great for me, which leads me to believe it is my specific jquery, html or css structure, or use of my template variables. Would love to get your thoughts

Comment: At this point, I recommend you to strip up your code, in small pieces, to find wich is the cause of the error. Perhaps you have another js library interfiering with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how .each works in jquery

```js
function toggleChks() {
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index, item) {
  console.log(index, item);
  if ($(item).prop('checked'))
    $(item).prop('checked', false);
  else
    $(item).prop('checked', true);
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="toggleChks()">toggle</button>
<input type="checkbox" checked value="1">
<input type="checkbox" checked value="2"> 
<input type="checkbox" checked value="3">
<input type="checkbox" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" value="6">
```

Comment: any suggestions on how to update my code with or without each?

Comment: why? what's the problem of using each? what's the goal?

Comment: all you did was give me an example of how each works -- I'd love some help actually using it to solve my problem if possible. Thank you!

Comment: I though that you could solve your problem with a working example. But anyway, I can help you If you give us more details of what's exactly your problem? You want to show/hide elements? if so, just have to change one line of my snippet. Could you create a working Snippet with your exact problem? So we could replicate and solve the problem?

Comment: thanks so much for the help -- I am trying to hide a different element, based on which checkbox you click. JSFiddle code here: https://jsfiddle.net/6p5hyk2n/1/#&togetherjs=y8DECIUQjl